# "Develop a python program to print square root of every alternate number in the range 1 to 15." What Do You Mean by alternate number?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I got a question in my recent computer test.

> *Develop a python program to print square root of every alternate number in
>   the range 1 to 15.*

I don't get the meaning of alternate number. Is it something like Fibonacci number or Perfect number? 
what is the mathematical meaning of alternate number and please solve this python program.

Comment: Best guess is they mean “every other number”? I’m wondering if they are trying to test whether you know how to use array steps.

Comment: Well, IDK. But this was asked in a High school test. So it must be something simple. Can you explain what is an alternate number in this case?

Comment: Did you try [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alternate#English)? *(mathematics) Designating the members in a series, which regularly intervene between the members of another series, as the odd or even numbers of the numerals; every other; every second. the alternate members 1, 3, 5, 7, etc.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question mentioned alternate number in the range of 1 to 15, I believe for every alternate you have to use step here.

```
import math  

[math.sqrt(i) for i in range(1, 15, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe alternating numbers means like Frank commented, every other number,
so in your case it'll be the odd or even numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate numbers in range 1 to 15 are simply 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15. That is, by removing the numbers on even or odd indices.

```
import math
for i in range(1,15):

    if i%2 != 0:
        print(math.sqrt(i))
```

Or you can do this:

```
import math
for i in range(1,15,2):
    print(math.sqrt(i))
```

Note: In the above code, 15 is not included.